# Linux (write) permissions will not be inherited for new files

Tags: linux, permissions

First I set the `setgid` bit, so that files/folder under directory will be created with the same group as directory.

```
chmod g+s <directory>
```

Then I tried to change the folder's permission structure, so that the group has `rwx` access to it by:

```
setfacl -R -m g::rwx /<directory>
```

## Problem

Now, `root` came by and creates a new folder (with files) under this directory which leads to:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root homecontrol 4096 May 11 20:20 '<folder>'
```

So `homecontrol` was set properly as group, but the write permission is missing.

Comment: I guess you just misunderstand the (stupid) output of `ls`... What is the output of `getfacl '/<directory>/<folder>'?

Comment: You are absolutely right!
`getfacl` on the directory displays proper permissions like: 

# owner: root
# group: homecontrol
group::rwx


So my problem is, that the owner is still **root**, which shall be **homecontrol**. Is there a way i can set the default owner to **homecontrol**?

Comment: You didn't mention this problem in your question even though the `ls` output made it quite clear that the owner is `root`...

Comment: I didn't know that i have a "owner" problem here, i thought it would be the missing write permission.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `default` keyword:

```
shadur@proteus:~/test$ mkdir testdir
shadur@proteus:~/test$ setfacl -m default:g::rwx testdir/
shadur@proteus:~/test$ touch testdir/test2
shadur@proteus:~/test$ ls -lsa testdir/
total 8
4 drwxr-xr-x+ 2 shadur shadur 4096 May 13 14:59 .
4 drwxr-xr-x  3 shadur shadur 4096 May 13 14:57 ..
0 -rw-rw-r--  1 shadur shadur    0 May 13 14:59 test2
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add -d to the command above. But newertheless, even with "default", there is no write permission for group after creating a new file afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enforce the owner of a new file; you can only change it after the file has been created. This can be done with

- a cron job / Systemd timer (very simple)
- inotify (i.e. `incrond` or `inotifywait`) if you need short response times or have directories with huge amounts of files